# How to chain a method call to a `do ... end` block in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, ruby-block

I'm doing the following:

```
array_variable = collection.map do |param|
  some value with param
end
return array_variable.compact
```

Can I call `map` and `compact` in one statement somehow, so I can return the result instantly?

I'm thinking on something like this (it may be invalid, however):

```
array_variable = block_code param.compact 
# block_code here is a method for example which fills the array
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. You can only call methods on objects, but blocks aren't objects, so you can't call methods on them. You can reify a block into a `Proc` object, and *then* you can call methods on it; but `Proc`s don't have a `compact` method. (What does it even *mean* to "compact a block"?)

Comment: I'm surely not all clear with Ruby at the moment. I want to compact the array object, but I'm filling it inside the do block. I did not say what I was thinking is good, I only wanted to clarify that I want to fill and compact the array in once. Like a function composition.

Comment: So, you are asking whether you can call a method on the return value of a method?

Comment: No. Stefan clarified the issue.

Comment: Now I am even more confused. You accepted an answer as correct which shows you how to call a method (in this case `compact`) on the return value of another method (in this case `map`), but that is not what you are asking? Then, what *is* it you are asking and why did you accept an answer that answers a question you are not asking?

Comment: A method which uses a do..end block. Yes, in this context this is what I was asking for, my bad.

Comment: I understood the question immediately and find it very useful.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

yes, you can call a method here.

In your case,

```
array_variable = collection.map do |param|
  # some value with param
end.compact
```

OR

```
array_variable = collection.map{ |param| some value with param }.compact
```

As pointed out by @Stefan, assignment is not required, you can directly use `return` and if that's the last line of method you can omit `return` too..

Comment: In your case, you are calling `compact` on the return value of `map` (which is an `Array`), while the question asks to "call method on a block". Now, I have no idea what "call method on a block" even means, but you are definitely calling `compact` on an `Array`.

Comment: yes ofcourse, it very much depends on the return type, since `map` returns an array and `compact` belongs to it it is good to go but not always..that's why I mentioned 'yes you can call a method here'

Comment: @JörgWMittag
I think you are slightly making an unnecessary quarrel, Md.FarhanMemon realized instantly what I want, surely you did as well. My question title was wrong, I admit.
But yes, I want to compact the result of the block, as it clearly mapped the return values into the array.

Comment: Note that the OP wants to return the result, so the assignment to `array_variable` is superfluous. Simply `return collection.map { ... }.compact` (you can even omit `return` if this is the method's last statement)

Comment: I personally am annoyed by the `end.compact` syntax, because the letters kind of run together, so it's easy to miss on a quick scan. My view is that there's nothing wrong with a multi-line block delimited by curly braces.